# .docm field update speed issue?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I seem to be having an issue when I load .docm forms containing OCX fields. If I update any formfields in the doc set to "Calculate on exit", without any macros firing, the update time is extremely long. If I open the doc and save it immediately then try and update the fields, they update quickly.

I only mention the OCX field types because when I delete them the form no longer has the update issue. I have also tried to switch from calculate on exit to a simple update macro that only updates ref fields, or one that updates all non OCX fields. Both have the same issue, although the macros ALWAYS take a long time to update the sheet, where calculations only do if I don't save first.

```
Sub UpdateRefFields()
Dim oField as Field
For Each oField In ActiveDocument.Fields
    If oField.Type = wdFieldRef Then
        oField.Update
    End If
Next oField
End Sub
```

Which takes just as long as:

`ActiveDocument.Fields.Update`

For *me* it's not an issue, but these are court forms that are required to be locked at all times, so the other users will not be able to save the document in advance prior... otherwise Calculate would work just fine.

Thoughts?

Comment: So why, for court forms,  are you using OCX controls (aka ActiveX controls), which are not supported on Macs - which are widely used amongst the legal fraternity? Also, please post your full code - including the code for your ActiveX controls and an explanation of their purpose.

Comment: What, more exactly, do you mean with "OCX fields"? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The controls are digital signature capture fields. They are inactive on the forms unless the user directly interacts with them. They don't need to be Mac compatible as all Judicial work in our district is required to be done on company computers, all of which are PCs.

Comment: The code would be of little use, they are mainly just calls to locked macros from the manufacturer's word add-in. All the macros entail is activation/deactivation of the signature capture device, and resetting the signature. I am positive they are doing nothing as the first command they run is to clear the current signature which does not occur.

Comment: I used a temporary fix of disabling the protection, saving the document, and re-enabling the protection when the document opens. It takes a couple seconds longer to load initially, but allows the form to work properly as its filled out.

Unfortuntely, this doesn't exactly resolve the underlying issue or identify the cause... but it allows the forms to be usable until I can figure out the cause.

Comment: Unless your add-in requires it, you don't need an ActiveX control for this. All you need do is leave the line where the digitial signature is to go in an unprotected part of the document. To do that simply insert a Section break before that line and, if applicable, another one after it, then leave that Section unprotected when applying the 'filling in forms' protection. Even if your adding requires the ActiveX control, putting that control in such an unprotected Section may resolve the issue. In any event, nothing you've described requires a docm document.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed significant saving in time updating fields if using VBA:

1. Save document
2. Close document
3. Open document
   then
4. Update fields

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have flagged your answer because the user has tried your solution and is asking for a permanent fix. Note question may have been changed after seeing your response and updated to include your suggestion.
" If I open the doc and save it immediately then try and update the fields, they update quickly."